# url address resolution past 2nd level

Tags: url, dynamic, web, dns, hosting

i got a new dynamic domain, say domain.com.
my local dns server has all the sites i use localy, say, mail.domain.com, nas.domain.com...and they point to the correct IP internally.
i only have 1 IP from my isp, and i am looking for a way to forward outside requests further.
if i go to nas.domain.com:80, it will still go to domain.com:80
i need a way to direct traffic to the proper place once the request hits my router/server.
note, mail and nas are separate machines.
hope this makes sense. 
thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Super late to answer my own question, but I found that I can implement a Squid Reverse Proxy server that can handle the routing.

Helpful Link:
http://www.visolve.com/squid/whitepapers/reverseproxy.php